# forms in django dose not retrive data and save it

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to create an appointment app with multiple condition

in theory i find a way to make it happend but it dose not save the data an give me an error message
the first part of the code work perfectly the 2nd part dose not save any data

i try a lot of things but nothing work

this is my code mybe some one see where the error is and give a hint to fix this

this is my views.py

```
@login_required
def create_appointement(request):
    user = User()
#################################this the first part#####################"this part work perfectly 
    if request.user.is_patient(): 
        form_appointement = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_appointement = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
            if form_appointement.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
                form_app.user_ho_add = request.user
                form_app.patient = request.user
                start_time = form_app.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_app.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')
        return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement1.html',{'form':form_appointement}) 
#################this is the 2nd part##################### this the part that give me always the error message and dont save any data 

    else:
        if request.method=='POST' and request.POST.get("type") == "register patient":
            
            form_appointment_2 = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
            user = User()
            user2 = get_user_model()
            patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
            if form_appointment_2.is_valid():
                form_appointment_2.save(commit=False)
                form_appointment_2.user_ho_add = request.user

                form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
                start_time = form_appointment_2.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_appointment_2.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)

                form_appointment_2.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')

            return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement2.html', {'user_form':form_appointment_2,'patients':patients })
        elif request.method=='POST' and request.POST.get("type") == "non register patient":
            form_appointment = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
            if form_appointment.is_valid():
                form_app = form_appointment.save(commit=False)
                form_app.user_ho_add = request.user
                form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
                start_time = form_appointment_2.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_appointment_2.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_app.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')
                
            return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement3.html',{'user_form':form_appointment, })
        else:
            return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement_options.html', )

        return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement_options.html', )
```

this is my forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm_2(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    # patient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT))
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    start_time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}), input_formats=settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('patient', 'doctor', 'date', 'start_time')

class AppointmentForm_3(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    start_time = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('patient', 'doctor', 'date', 'start_time')
```

and this is my html files

add_appointement_otions.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="from-group">
                <label for="">select the type of appointment</label>
                <select name="type" id="">
                    <option value="">-- select type --</option>
                    <option value="register patient">register patient</option>
                    <option value="non register patient">non register patient</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" value="create_appointment">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

and the add_appointement3.html

```
<body>
    {% if user_form.errors %} {% for field in user_form %} {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{ field.label }}</strong><span>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in user_form.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post">
            
             {{ user_form.media }} {{ user_form.as_p }}  {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointment">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? That's a lot of code to find a mistake in... What do you call the 1st part and 2nd part? What do you expect to be saved ? etc...

Comment: add it in the code in the views.py file

Comment: What is the value of `request.POST.get("type")` ?

Comment: the first value is "register patient" and the 2nd is "non register patient" in the html file add_appointement_options.html

Comment: Can you add `print(form_appointment_2.errors)` before your message error, and look at what the console outputs ?

Comment: it show me this error `<ul class="errorlist"><li>doctor<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>date<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is
required.</li></ul></li><li>start_time<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>` but before I writ any data in the form and after that it show nothing

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to write for every form a own view, checked the code and did adjust it a little, you can give it a try and share the responses:

@login_required

```
def create_appointement(request):
# Giving user a variable
user = User()

# Check if user is patient and if there is a post request
#POST REQUESTS
if request.user.is_patient() and if request.method=='POST':
    #Retrieving data from form
    form_appointement = AppointmentForm(request.POST or None)
    #Validating data
    if form_appointement.is_valid():
        # manipulate data
        form_app = form_appointement.save(commit=False)
        form_app.user_ho_add = request.user
        form_app.patient = request.user
        start_time = form_app.start_time
        future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
        form_app.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
        # Saving data
        form_app.save()
        #Returning message
        messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
    # if form is not valid
    else:
        #returning message
        messages.error(request, 'Error')

    return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement1.html',{'form':form_appointement})

# POST request with other kind of patient
elif request.method=='POST' and request.POST.get("type") == "register patient":

    # Giving form a new variable and retrieving data
    form_appointment_2 = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)

    #Getting second user
    user2 = get_user_model()
    #Getting patients out of user 2
    patients = user2.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
    #Validating data form new for
    if form_appointment_2.is_valid():
        #manipulating form data
        form_appointment_2.save(commit=False)
        form_appointment_2.user_ho_add = request.user
        form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
        start_time = form_appointment_2.start_time
        future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
        form_appointment_2.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
        #Saving form
        form_appointment_2.save()
        #returning message
        messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
    else:
        #returning message
        messages.error(request, 'Error')
    return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement2.html', {'user_form':form_appointment_2,'patients':patients })

elif request.method=='POST' and request.POST.get("type") == "non register patient":

    # Giving form a new variable and retrieving data
    form_appointment = AppointmentForm_3(request.POST or None)
    #Validating data form new for
    if form_appointment.is_valid():
        #manipulating form data
        form_app = form_appointment.save(commit=False)
        form_app.user_ho_add = request.user
        form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
        start_time = form_appointment_2.start_time
        future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
        form_appointment_2.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
        #Saving form
        form_app.save()
        #returning message
        messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
    else:
        #returning message
        messages.error(request, 'Error')

    return render(request,'appointement/add_appointement3.html',{'user_form':form_appointment})
    
else:
    return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement_options.html', )
```

Comment: you make the code more clear, but it steel have the same problem, so sorry and thank you

Comment: Make a index page with the 3buttons that redirect to the form, further add 3 views with each form and check if the user is allowed to use this form. This prevents you from debugging the wrong form in the same view.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens because you try to pass an additional keyword argument which the form is not supposed to handle (type). Can you try the following:

```py
# in your second part
    else:
        request.POST._mutable = True
        type = request.POST.pop("type")
        request.POST._mutable = False
        if request.method=='POST' and type == "register patient":
        ### rest of this part looks ok
        elif request.method=='POST' and type == "non register patient":
        ### rest of this part looks ok
```

Comment: now it show me this error `Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

This QueryDict instance is immutable`

Comment: @houhou I edited my answer.... Can you check again ? thanks.

Comment: now it give this one `Exception Type:  KeyError Exception Value:'type'`i try it with the `type = request.POST.pop("type", True)`or `type = request.POST.pop("type", False)` and it didt work, thank you and I'm sorry I bothered you